# Как заставить разработчиков, чтобы их callback функции возвращали только нужный тип

Tags: php, ооп

У меня есть такой метод:

```
public function getSectionPath(array $params, callable $callback = null) : ?returObjectType {
    ...
    if(null !== $callback && is_callable($callback)) {
         return $callback();
    }
    ...
}
```

По Type Hinting понятно, что метод всегда должен возвращать `returObjectType` либо `null`, также необходимо возвращать результат callback-функции, если он указан.

Но разработчики не знают, какой тип должен возвращать callback.

Есть ли какие-то варианты решения проблема без костылей? Т.е. классно было бы, чтобы они все реализовывали callback таким образом (указывать возвращаемый тип):

```
$this->getSectionPath([..], function () use (...) : \returObjectType {
   ...
});
```

Единственное решение, которое приходит в голову, это в методе перед возвращением значения callback проверять его тип.

Comment: Если разработчики управляемы (свои, либо им за эту разработку платят) - просто поставить им соответствующее требование как обязательное.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, стоит использовать общий интерфейс и классы со статическим методом вместо callback.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть ваши программисты передают в метод не callable, а некий task-объект, реализующий интерфейс `TaskInterface`. Тогда и вы и они будете обязаны следовать контрактам:

```
<?php

interface returnObjectTypeInterface
{
}

interface TaskInterface
{
    public function executed(): returnObjectTypeInterface;
}

public function getSectionPath(array $params, TaskInterface $task = null) : ?returnObjectTypeInterface {
    ...
    if ($task !== null) {
        return $task->executed();
    }
    ...
}
```